# Loading Image File from AWS with Picasso

Tags: android, amazon-s3, picasso

New to Picasso here. I'm trying to load an image stored on AWS (specifially S3) into my Android app using Picasso but I keep getting a blank image with no errors in my logcat and nothing obvious to me from general debugging around the relevant lines of code.

The image is stored on AWS which is in development mode and currently public so it shouldn't be an issue of logins etc. I also have internet permissions enabled in my manifest.

The code does seems to work when I save a random image link on the internet but I noticed when I use my browser to go to those links it opens up a page displaying nothing but that image. The database on S3, however, is set up to auto-download the file instead of displaying such a page. Perhaps that's the cause of my problem?

Here are 2 versions of my code, neither has worked for my image on AWS (note I'm substituting my real link to AWS with AWSLink but my actual code uses the real link):

Version 1

```
mApartmentImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.details_page_apartment_picture);  
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("//AWSLink.jpg").into(mApartmentImageView);
```

Version 2 (tries to account for auto-download of file)

```
mApartmentImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.details_page_apartment_picture);
String path = "//AWSLink.jpg";
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(new File(path)).into(mApartmentImageView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String path = "//AWSLink.jpg";
path is not a valid one, Use appropriate path and check

Picasso have callbacks, use those and check.

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(new File(path)).into(mApartmentImageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
        }
    });
```

Before that, pass proper file path. Try to hit the file path in browser, If the path is giving image then use it as a parameter in load method

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(getContext())
        .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                //Here your log
            }
        })
        .build(); picasso.load(new File(path)).into(mApartmentImageView);
```

Comment: correct the link i put in the code in my question is not the actual link, just a dummy link. dumb question but should i just error log stuff in onError i.e. { Log.e etc etc } ?

Comment: If u want to check exception, u can use listener to find. modified the code, please check it

Comment: it is indeed failing to load the image. still thinking it must have to do with the fact that the url / file path auto downloads the jpg instead of displaying a page with just the image as this link would: //http://square.github.io/picasso/static/debug.png

Comment: Well the bottom section of your code combined with suddenly works for me whereas it didn't yesterday.

Comment: didn't mean to hit enter there - Well the bottom section of your code combined with version 1 of my code (just use url don't assume its a File) suddenly works for me whereas it didn't yesterday. hell just tried using version 1 of my code straight up again and it suddenly works. not sure how that's possible but i guess I'll take it. Thanks for the help Harsha